# How to Download a pdf Using the response from service

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

my code

```
var url = getApplicationRoot() + '/api/dossier/report/pdfReport?reportId='+reportid;
            console.log(url);
            $http.get( url, {cache: false} )
            .success( function( data )
            {
                //success(data);
                console.log(data);
                if(success){
                    window.open( getApplicationRoot() + '/api/dossier/report/pdfReport?reportId='+reportid);
                }
            })
```

I am able to download as pdf ,but its opening in another window and downloading because i given window .open  .How can i make in the same window .As like normal download .
I am using angular MVC .

Firfox it is working fine .But in Chrome it is opening in new window

Comment: I got the answer , i used window.location.href   instead of window.open and its working as desired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using **window.open(...)** you can use an iframe or the window.location:

```
// iframe
var ifrm = document.getElementById(frame);
ifrm.src = getApplicationRoot() + '/api/dossier/report/pdfReport?reportId='+reportid;

// in the same window
window.location=getApplicationRoot() + '/api/dossier/report/pdfReport?reportId='+reportid;
```

Comment: Thank you , i used window.location.href  and its working

Answer (score 1):

Just add `'_self'` as a second parameter to `window.open()`.

```
window.open(getApplicationRoot() + '/api/dossier/report/pdfReport?reportId=' + reportid, '_self');
```

Comment: Thank you , but i have fixed the issue long back

Answer (score 0):

I used this jQuery plugin from Filament Group to do something similar:
https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-File-Download